# pandas, combining multiple dataframes

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a python program that Does the following.

- reads in a .csv
- creates a dataframe with values from specific columns of the csv
- converts the timestamp from unix timestamp
- groups the data by hour and then Finds the average of certain data in that hour.

code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(files,parse_dates=True)
df2 = df[['timestamp','avg_hr','avg_rr','emfit_sleep_summary_id']]
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'].astype(int)
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['timestamp'],unit='s')

df2 = df2.set_index('timestamp')
df3 = df2.groupby(df2.index.map(lambda t: t.hour))['avg_hr'].mean()
df4 = df2.groupby(df2.index.map(lambda t: t.hour))['avg_rr'].mean()

print df3
print df4
```

sample output:

```
       timestamp         avg_hr  avg_rr    emfit_sleep_summary_id
0 2015-01-28 08:14:50     101     6.4                      78
1 2015-01-28 08:14:52      98     6.4                      78
2 2015-01-28 00:25:00      60     0.0                      78 
3 2015-01-28 00:25:02      63     0.0                      78
4 2015-01-28 07:24:06      79    11.6                      78
5 2015-01-28 07:24:08      79    11.6                      78
0    99.5
7    61.5
8    78.5
Name: avg_hr, dtype: float64
0     0.000
7    11.725
8     6.400
Name: avg_rr, dtype: float64
```

I'm now trying to combine `df3` and `df4` into `df2` so  the result will look something like this:

```
       timestamp         avg_hr  avg_rr    emfit_sleep_summary_id   AVG_HR    AVG_RR
0 2015-01-28 08:14:50     101     6.4                      78        99.5       6.4 
1 2015-01-28 08:14:52      98     6.4                      78        99.5       6.4
2 2015-01-28 00:25:00      60     0.0                      78        61.5       0.0
3 2015-01-28 00:25:02      63     0.0                      78        61.5       0.0
4 2015-01-28 07:24:06      79    11.6                      78        78.5       11.6
5 2015-01-28 07:24:08      79    11.6                      78        78.5       11.6
```

I tried doing the following

```
df2['AVG_HR'] = df2.groupby(df2.index.map(lambda t: t.hour))['avg_hr'].mean()
```

But when I ran, it returned `NAN` for the entire column.

**EDIT:** I'd also know how to reduce the number of rows to a single one for each hour, instead of having 2 per hour.

```
       timestamp         avg_hr  avg_rr    emfit_sleep_summary_id   AVG_HR    AVG_RR
0 2015-01-28 08:14:50     101     6.4                      78        99.5       6.4 
1 2015-01-28 00:25:00      60     0.0                      78        61.5       0.0
2 2015-01-28 07:24:06      79    11.6                      78        78.5       11.6
```

Comment: I think what you want is this: `df2['AVG_HR'] = df2.groupby(df2.index.map(lambda t: t.hour))['avg_hr'].transofrm('mean')` can you confirm

Comment: Also you don't need a lambda to groupby the hour this should work: `df3 = df2.groupby(df2.index.hour)['avg_hr'].mean()`

Comment: @EdChum that worked, if you could post that as the answer, I'll accept it. Also, wondering, is there any way to reduce the rows? instead of having 2 of each timestamp, can I have just one?

Comment: So you want to reduce `df2` to a single row per hour? In which case are you wanting the average of the aggregated columns or the sum? `df2.groupby(df2.index.hour).mean().reset_index()` should squeeze the df to an hourly one, also you could resample

Comment: yes, instead of 2 timesstamps, I need one per hour. I want the average to remain as is. Please see the edit.

Comment: I've posted an edit, you can call `mean` on the groupby object and then call `reset_index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a aggregated column from a groupby use `transform` this will return a Series aligned with the original df:

```
df2['AVG_HR'] = df2.groupby(df2.index.map(lambda t: t.hour))['avg_hr'].transofrm('mean')
```

Also it's unnecessary to use a lambda to groupby the hour, the index, if it is a DateTimeindex has the datetime attributes that can be accessed directly so the above can be simplified to:

```
df2['AVG_HR'] = df2.groupby(df2.index.hour)['avg_hr'].transform('mean')
```

If you want to resample by hour you could just groupby the hour and then call `reset_index`:

```
In [17]:

df.groupby(df.index.hour).mean().reset_index()
Out[17]:
   index  avg_hr  avg_rr  emfit_sleep_summary_id
0      0    61.5     0.0                      78
1      7    79.0    11.6                      78
2      8    99.5     6.4                      78
```

Comment: I suppose there is no way to make the datetime stay? instead of `0`, `7`, `8`

Comment: Not using groupby, the alternative would be to call `drop_duplicates` on your df after you've added the average columns but that doesn't average the other duplcate columns

Comment: I did this `df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset='AVG_HR',take_last=True)` and that worked :)

Comment: But that won't average out say 'avg_hr' though if that's what you want then that's fine, I would've posted that but thought you wanted to average all values, you can upvote too ;-)

Comment: I got the avg_hr using `df2['AVG_HR'] = df2.groupby(df2.index.hour)['avg_hr'].transform('mean')` this would add an extra column, I used that column to filter the hours. same with avg_rr

Comment: Ah OK, well glad I could help in what little way I could